# The Pgn reader controls are far down the page

Tags: support, bug, pgn-viewer

When accessing the website on mobile, I find that the pgn controls are far down the page and it takes a second to scroll down, meaning that I can’t go through the moves while viewing the moves. I instead must press ‘next’, scroll all the way up to see what happened, then scroll all the way down to do it again.

Comment: I have the same issue!

Answer (score 1):

If you can click on a computer, you can click on the first move and use your arrow keys.

Comment: I mentioned that I’m on mobile.

Comment: @fartgeek My bad.

Answer (score 0):

I proposed replacing the current PGN viewer with something less buggy since it doesn't seem like the current viewer is being maintained.

[Proposal: replace current PGN viewer](https://chess.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1119/proposal-replace-current-pgn-viewer)